# If status=1 =>"Есть в наличии",else "Нет в наличии" Laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, laravel

Всем привет. У меня есть таблица "Products" в ней есть поле "Status", она принимает Булевы значения, но как на выходе преобразовывать его в слова "Есть/нет в наличие"?

Где именно прописать это правило и можно ли вообще как-то выходящие данные из БД преобразовывать?

Полагаю нужен middleware? Само условие вроде простое, но как его во вьюхе потом использовать?

Пытался в модели "Product" прописать, но как из модели обратиться к полю в БД, так ведь работать не будет?

```
    public function isAvailable(){
    if(DB::where('status','1')){
      echo 'Есть в наличии';
    }else{
      echo 'Нет в наличии';
    } 
  }
```

В программирование не так давно, поэтому если банальщину спрашиваю не ругайтесь. Теорию читал, но на практике лучше усваивается)
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Мидлвари немного для другого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если делаете через модель Product то достаточно добавить мутатор для модели

```
public function getIsAvailableAttribute() {
    return $this->status === 1 ? 'Есть в наличии' : 'Нет в наличии';
}
```

Теперь когда во вьюхе будете обращаться к экземпляру этой модели можете использовать `$product->is_available`

Comment: Супер! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Да не за что=) Это вроде база для лары

Comment: не кажется ли вам, что подобные сообщения имеет смысл выносить в локализации, а не прописывать в коде?

Comment: более того, сей вопрос лучше вообще в на уровне шаблона решать.

Comment: @teran с локализацией согласен, на уровне шаблона не совсем... Если это в нескольких местах надо выводить будет, с минимальной разницей, можно наплодить лишнего... Хотя и в шаблонах можно сделать инклюды и компоненты

Comment: а никто и не мешает в шаблоне локализацию использовать.